Show bounding box of shapes/nodes with specified attributes (width, color, etc.)
I would like to automate showing the bounding box of shapes/nodes. At the moment I'm using a scope and its local bounding box property to achieve this, as this is the best solution I found so far. Here's a minimal example:
\documentclass[border={2pt 2pt 2pt 2pt}]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}[local bounding box=aabb1]
        \draw[thick, fill=green] (0.5, 0.0) circle (1.0);
    \end{scope}
    \draw[red] (aabb1.south west) rectangle (aabb1.north east);

    \begin{scope}[local bounding box=aabb2]
        \node[star, star points=6, draw=black, minimum size=2cm, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt] at (-1.5,1.0) {};
    \end{scope}
    \draw[red] (aabb2.south west) rectangle (aabb2.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

The result is this lovely simple figure:

Ideally, I would like to automate this somehow - but using a macro seems a bit too clunky. I was hoping there would be some way to simply add an attribute to \draw or \node that will show the bounding-box in a specific width and color of my choice. Does anyone have any idea how to achieve that?

\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfsetlayers{background, main, foreground}
\tikzset{
showbb/.style={path picture={
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
\draw[#1] (path picture bounding box.south west) rectangle (path picture bounding box.north east);
\end{pgfonlayer}
}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[showbb={blue, ultra thick}, draw, star, star points=6, minimum size=2cm, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt] at (-1.5,1.0) {};
\draw[showbb={red, dashed}, thick, fill=green] (0.5, 0.0) circle[radius=1];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


As commented by @Sigur, the rectangle is rotated - it is not wanted, so it is better just to draw lines like this:
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfsetlayers{background, main, foreground}
\tikzset{
showbb/.style={path picture={
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
\draw[#1] (path picture bounding box.south west) -- (path picture bounding box.north west) -- (path picture bounding box.north east) -- (path picture bounding box.south east)-- cycle;
\end{pgfonlayer}
}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[rotate=30, showbb={red}] (0,0) rectangle (2,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Was foreground used?

No foreground is not used, but I prefer to always define both and set them in that order. Here OP even might want to use it instead of background to make the box on top of shape.

Interesting. I never used layers but I imagine how useful they could be.

\draw[rotate=30,showbb={red}] (0,0) rectangle (2,1); does not work as expected. Do you have idea how to fix it?

Incredible! This is exactly what I wanted :) thanks!

Oh, @Sigur is correct, it doesn't work with rotate... Still very useful for me though.

@pelegs: See edit

@pelegs, yes, very very useful.

With the edit it is now perfect :)

If you need something frequently, just create a pic:

\documentclass[border={2pt 2pt 2pt 2pt}]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
%% mybb ===========================
pics/mybb/.style n args={2}{
code={%%
\path[draw=#2] (#1.south west) rectangle (#1.north east);
},%%
},% =====
]
\begin{scope}[local bounding box=aabb1]
\draw[thick, fill=green] (0.5, 0.0) circle (1.0);
\end{scope}
%\draw[red] (aabb1.south west) rectangle (aabb1.north east);% old

\begin{scope}[local bounding box=aabb2]
\node[star, star points=6, draw=black, minimum size=2cm, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt] at (-1.5,1.0) {};
\end{scope}
%\draw[red] (aabb2.south west) rectangle (aabb2.north east);% old


\pic{mybb={aabb2}{blue}};% new

\pic{mybb={aabb1}{red}};% new
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


scope is still necessary in this case.
